# How to find specific lines of a text file and do some operations on them?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have several `.c` files, and I want to find lines with `printf`, and for those lines, I want to add `//` before them to comment out the code. I can use python the read each file, do the transformation, and write transformed text back, but it's too complex. Are there any other easy ways? I considered things like `sed` and `awk`, but I don't know how to write the expression, or whether it is possible to complete this task using `sed`/`awk`.

Comment: No, it is not possible to do this job robustly without a parser for the specific C variant your code is written in. Any posted answer will fail given some input file contents.

Answer (score 5):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/printf/s~^~//~g' *.c
```

Suggested by @SLePort,

```
sed 's~.*printf~//&~' *.c
```

Use `-i` for in-place edit.

Another way for matching exactly `printf` (Assuming `printf` always starts in newline):

```
sed 's~^\([\t ]*\)\(printf\)~\1//\2~g' file
```

Comment: Or maybe `sed 's~.*printf~//&~'`. And I'm not sure the `g`modifier is useful here.

Answer (score 3):

In awk. It's untested as there was no sample data and I had no .c files around:

```
$ awk '/printf/ { sub(/^/,"//") } 1' *.c
```

Explained:

- `/printf/` for records with `printf` on them
- `sub(/^/,"//")` add to the beginning of record `//`
- `1` implicit print

This solution will print output to stdout which may be a bit problematic for processing several files. One way of dealing with that is to use Gnu awk v. 4.1.0 or higher and *inplace edit*: `gawk -i inplace`.
Another would be to output to other files, for example by changing the implicit print to `{ print > "edited-" FILENAME }` to print each edited file to a new file (for example `file.c` to `edited-file.c`). Frankly, I'd use @sat's `sed` solution myself.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ed`, the standard editor available since `UNIX`-days (portable, `POSIX` compatible) and a loop to do in-place replacement,

```
for i in *.c; do
    printf '%s\n' ",g/printf/ s/^/\/\//" w q | ed -s -- "$i"
done
```

In,

```
,g/printf/ s/^/\/\//
```

`,g/printf/` marks all lines containing `printf` and `s/^/\/\//` adds the word  `//` to those lines. Then `wq` writes the file and closes it subsequently.

Use a command-line friendly version in a single line as,

```
for i in *.c; do printf '%s\n' ",g/printf/ s/^/\/\//" w q | ed -s -- "$i"; done
```

(or) using `ex` editor the command-line equivalent of  `Vim`

```
for i in *.c; do printf '%s\n' "%g/printf/ s/^/\/\//" w q | ex -s "$i"; done
```

Comment: Thanks for using a _text editor_ and not a _stream editor_ to edit a _file_ `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/printf/ s/^/\/\//'  filename
```